# getting no data when using datatables in laravel with yajra

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, yajra-datatable

I'm setting up a datatable for users and there privileges from a pivot 
but im getting a blank screen after following up the documentation
these are the files/methodes i used

datatable.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#user_table').DataTable({
    processing:true,
    serverSide:true,
    ajax:{
        url: "{{route('utilisateurs')}}",
    },
    columns:[
        {data: 'name',name: 'name'},
        {data: 'cin',name: 'cin'},
        {data: 'tel',name: 'tel'},
        {data: 'adresse',name: 'adresse'},
        {data: 'email',name: 'email'},
        {data: 'nom_utilisateur',name: 'nom_utilisateur'},
        {data: 'libelle_privilege',name: 'libelle_privilege'},
    ]
});

});
```

ComptesController@getData and @index

```
public function index(){
$privilege = Privilege::all();
        return view('pages.utilisateurs')->with('privileges',$privilege);}
public function getData(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $users = User::all();
        return Datatables::of($users)
            ->addColumn('libelle_privilege',function(User $user){
                return $user->privileges()->latest()->first()->libelle_privilege;
            })
            ->make(true);
    }
}
```

utilisateurs.blade.php table

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-3 dataTable 
    server-side" id="user_table" role="grid" aria- 
    describedby="user_table_info">
    <thead>
    <tr role="row">
        <th class="sorting_asc" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria- 
        sort="ascending">Nom</th>
        <th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1">CIN</th>
        <th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Téléphone</th>
        <th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Adresse</th>
        <th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Email</th>
        <th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Nom d'utilisateur</th>
        <th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Privilèges</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Nom</th>
        <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">CIN</th>
        <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Téléphone</th>
        <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Adresse</th>
        <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Email</th>
        <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Nom d'utilisateur</th>
        <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Privilèges</th>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
    </table>
```

web.php

```
Route::get('utilisateurs', 'ComptesController@index')->name('utilisateurs');
Route::get('utilisateurs/getData', 'ComptesController@getData')->name('utilisateurs.getData');
```

Comment: You should not use same HTTP verbs and URI to call different controller method.

Comment: ok im gonna try moving PagesController@utilisateurs to ComptesController

Comment: the blank screen is gonne but there's no data i updated the post thx

Comment: what error you are getting on console?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at utilisateurs:580
jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).DataTable is not a function TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function

Comment: What you can see if you are clicking on that error in console?

Comment: for the error jQuery.Deferred exception
i see
w.Deferred.exceptionHook

Comment: Can you change the table id in html and js and reload it again and see, if you are getting same error?

Comment: yes im getting the same errors

Comment: Can you confirm if `$user->privileges()->latest()->first()` is string also can you remove the `<tfoot></tfoot>` section.

Comment: $user->privileges return an array of strings so i try
                    return $user->privileges()->libelle_privilege->latest()->first();
but not working

Comment: what you are getting in tinker Can you check and put here?

Comment: this return a string
$user->privileges()->latest()->first()->libelle_privilege;

Comment: After this also you are getting the same error?

Comment: yes same errors

Comment: Can you try my code and let me know the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jS

```
 var url = "{{ url('/utilisateurs/getData') }}";
    $(document).ready(function () {
$('#user_table').DataTable({
    processing:true,
    serverSide:true,
    ajax:{
        url: url,
    },
    columns:[
        {data: 'name',name: 'name'},
        {data: 'cin',name: 'cin'},
        {data: 'tel',name: 'tel'},
        {data: 'adresse',name: 'adresse'},
        {data: 'email',name: 'email'},
        {data: 'nom_utilisateur',name: 'nom_utilisateur'},
        {data: 'libelle_privilege',name: 'libelle_privilege'},
    ]
});

});
```

and  in controller as you are adding new column

```
 public function getData(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {
    $users = User::all();
    return Datatables::of($users)
        ->addColumn('libelle_privilege',function(User $user){
            if ($user->privileges()->exists()) {
                $privileges = $user->privileges()->pluck('libelle_privilege')->toArray();
                return implode(" ",$privileges);
            }
            return 'non';
        })
        ->make(true);
}
}
```

In your view

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="user_table">
    <thead>
    <tr role="row">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1">CIN</th>
        <th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Téléphone</th>
        <th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Adresse</th>
        <th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Email</th>
        <th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Nom d'utilisateur</th>
        <th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Privilèges</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    </table>
```

make this changes and let me know the status.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192398/discussion-on-answer-by-prafulla-kumar-sahu-getting-no-data-when-using-datatable).

Answer (score 0):

The url in your js is not good i think :

```
 url: "{{route('utilisateurs.getData')}}",
```

Comment: i don't know its my first time with datatables

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
   // Add this on the top
   use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Builder;
   use DataTables;

   //Controller index method for listing

    public function index(Builder $builder, Request $request)
    {
        $privilege = Privilege::all();

        if (request()->ajax()) {
               return Datatables::of($privilege)
                ->addColumn('libelle_privilege',function(User $user){
                    return $user->privileges()->latest()->first();
                })
                ->make(true);
         }
        $html = $builder->columns([
        ['data' => 'name', 'name' => 'name', 'title' => 'Name','width'=>'10%'],
        ['data' => 'cin', 'name' => 'cin', 'title' => 'Cin','width'=>'10%'],
        ['data' => 'tel', 'name' => 'tel', 'title' => 'Tel','width'=>'10%'],
        ['data' => 'adresse', 'name' => 'adresse', 'title' => 'Address','width'=>'40%'],
        ['data' => 'email', 'name' => 'email', 'title' => 'Email','width'=>'5%'],
        ['data' => 'nom_utilisateur', 'name' => 'nom_utilisateur', 'title' => 'Nom_Utukusateur','width'=>'5%'],
        ['data' => 'libelle_privilege', 'name' => 'libelle_privilege', 'title' => 'Libelle Privilege','width'=>'5%'],
        ])->parameters([
            'order' =>'1',
            'paging'      => true,
            'info'        => false,
            'searchDelay' => 350,
            'dom'         => 'Bfrtip',
            'buttons'     => ['print', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf'],
            'searching'   => true,
        ]);
        return view('pages.utilisateurs',compact('html'));
    }

    // In Blade file render tables

    <div class="table-responsive">
            {!! $html->table(['class' => 'table table-striped'], true) !!}
    </div>
```

No js required in blade at all

Comment: its give me this error 
Class App\Http\Controllers\Builder does not exist
i think i need to import something

Comment: add this on the top `use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Builder;`